# What does it mean to run a Polygon zkNode without the zkProver?

Tags: polygon, zero-knowledge, l2, zkevm

I was going through the "Setup Local zkNode" section in the Polygon zkEVM Developer Guides and came across the following line: [If you are unable to meet the Prover requirements, you can still run the zkNode](https://zkevm.polygon.technology/setup-local-node/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20unable%20to%20meet%20the%20Prover%20requirements%2C%20you%20can%20still%20run%20the%20zkNode.). I have a few questions related to this:

1. What does it actually mean? Are [zkNode](https://github.com/0xPolygonHermez/zkevm-node) and [zkProver](https://github.com/0xPolygonHermez/zkevm-prover) separately
   executable?
2. Can I run zkNode without the zkProver locally (considering I don't have the [resources](https://zkevm.polygon.technology/setup-local-node/#:%7E:text=you%27ll%20need%20at%20least%201TB%20of%20RAM) to run a zkProver on my system)?
3. When I execute the 'make run' command in the zkNode directory, is it running without the zkProver?
4. If it is, I still see a zk-prover docker container created. What's that for?

Sorry for asking so many questions in the same thread, I am quite confused.
Original discussion post [here](https://github.com/0xPolygonHermez/zkevm-node/discussions/2317), but asking on ETH StackExchange as I got no response so far.